# casperjs click twitter button

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

i use casperjs for automatical click on twitter share button. Twitter use iframe for create this buttons:

```
<iframe src="some src">

</iframe>
```

When i click it open popup window, but when i trying to login into twitter, i got error, `form not found`

```
casper.withFrame(0) { //it twitter iframe
   this.fill("#twitter-widget-0 form#update-form", {
     "session[username_or_email]": "myemail@email.com",
     "session[password]": "password"
  }, true);
});
```

Why? It possible with casperjs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Twitter widgets, but are you sure **#twitter-widget-0** is not the id of the iframe you just switched in to? It seems that way, because I found code like this: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11450

If you switched into the iframe, you cannot access elements from the parent page anymore, and you are trying to access the iframe element, which resides in the parent.
You should just select **form#update-form**, because it's not a child element of **#twitter-widget-0**: it is just an element that is contained in the iframe.

If so, the solution is simply omitting **#twitter-widget-0** from your selector inside the iframe.

```
casper.withFrame(0) { //it twitter iframe
   this.fill("form#update-form", {
     "session[username_or_email]": "myemail@email.com",
     "session[password]": "password"
  }, true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, but this not work, for twitter the best choice - use a callback function. In page code have function some like this:
`on("tweet", function() { $.ajax(send on server event fired for current session)  }); and in casperjs use functions for ajax send:
`JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX(url, t, data, false));`